# Trying to get a right callout button to load another view controller

Tags: ios, xcode, ios4

I am creating a walking tour and am using mapkit.  I have the map loading and am using custom icons as pins and loading my gps coordinates from a plist file.  My callouts are working fine.  My problem is that I would like the right callout button to load different information on another screen for each stop (picture of stop and an MP3).  Would I load a different view controller for each stop on the tour?  If so what code would I add to this following to have a view controller named Detailcontroller load?

```
 - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    NSLog(@"I've been tapped");
}
```

If I am way off and someone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated. I apologize for my wording as I am really new to coding/app development.

Answer (score 0):

I would hope and expect that you'd use the same kind of view controller for each stop, but set up with different data. When I've done something like this, my annotations have been the data objects for each point of interest on the map, so I'd do this:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    StopInfo *stopInfo = view.annotation;
    StopInfoDetailController *detailController = [[StopInfoDetailController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    detailController.stopInfo = stopInfo;
    [mapView.navigationController pushViewController:detailController animated:YES];
    [detailController release];
}
```

In this case, StopInfo would be the class of the annotation objects. It should contain the information that the detail controller needs to do it's thing: MP3 file name, stop location, stop image file name, stop description, etc.

Note that you might actually have several different kinds of annotations on your map. Maybe some are stops on your walking tour while others are points of interest that aren't on the tour, food vendors, bathrooms, etc. In that case you might want to use different view controllers for each type of anntation, so you'd look at the annotation object to figure out what kind of view controller to instantiate.

Comment: Do I create a new class called StopInfo?  Where do I add the Mp3 file name and image file names? How do I make it pull different info for each stop?  Do I create a new class called StopInfo?  Do you have a sample of this?  Sorry for all the questions.

Comment: Well, what are your annotations? When you load the map, you add a bunch of objects that implement the MKAnnotation protocol, right? I'd guess that you probably have some set of objects where each represents a stop, with the stop name and location (since those are the things you need to provide when you adopt MKAnnotation). Whatever class that is, that's where I'd also store the other data that your stop detail controller needs. That's your StopInfo class (feel free to change it in the source above, naturally).

Comment: This post solved my problem http://mayurbirari.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/how-to-access-mkmapkit-in-iphone/